# Error Importing three.js through npm and browserify

Tags: javascript, npm, three.js, browserify, require

i'm very new to npms and i'm trying to import three.js into my scene but it is coming up with this error despite stating the `type = "module"` in my script tag in my html
[image]
 I installed it through an npm and here is my javascript:

```
var $ = require('jquery');

var three = require('three');

import * as THREE from 'three';
 import OrbitControls from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';

var camera, scene, renderer;
var geometry, material, mesh;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10 );
    camera.position.z = 1;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 0.2, 0.2, 0.2 );
    material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( mesh );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
    mesh.rotation.y += 0.02;

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#"/>
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type = "module" src="/bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Sorry if the answer is obvious, using browserify and module files is very new territory for me.

Edit: So in the official documentation, it says to do this :

```
var THREE = require('three');

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
...
```

which works except I want to use

```
import { MapControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
```

which is only available through extracting it from the orbitcontrols library. Is there a way to do this without ES6 imports and using `require()` instead?

Comment: Why are you using require and browserfy in the first place? Just use imports. Then use babel if you want to support older browsers.

Comment: "So in the official documentation, it says to do this"......[The documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Import-via-modules) says to use **require or import**, not both

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment @2pha. I am using this since it is easier to organize my files and also I am trying to use three.js in conjuction with tween and threex.domevents.js and they both didn't seem to work well when using import. I have tried the official documentation and it works however I want to use    ` import { MapControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
`
which is only available through extracting it from the orbitcontrols library and I don't know how to do this through require. I have tried using just Imports and no require() but the error still occurs

Comment: threex.domevents is pretty old, but [this issue](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/threex.domevents/issues/28) shows how to make it work with es6 imports., What "tween" are you referring to? As far as I can see, Browserfy expects you to load modules with require, not import. So I think you have to choose to use browserfy and require, or use imports, not both.